# Get an average monthly view of active members (Postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, date, sum, pivot, average

I am working with members data. I have the responsible Coach, the coachee entry, exit status and date. Because some coachees might graduate/leave during a month I want to calculate a daily number and then get a monthly average of active members for each coach. That means that I need to take in the account all coachees from previous months, that are still active that current month. This is my data:

[image]

I am thinking of creating a variable first where I can get the daily active member count for each coach. This is my first approach:

```
with all_years as (
    select y.year, m.month, d.day
    from generate_series(2019, 2022) as y(year)
             cross join generate_series(1, 12) as m(month)
             cross join generate_series(1, 31) as d(day) --<<*not sure how to adjust for days with less than 31 days??*
        select ay.*, coach, coachee, entry_status, entry_date, exit_reason, exit_date, sum(count) over (partition by ay.coach order by ay.year, ay.month, ay.day)
    from all_years ay
        left join table t
    on --.... *not sure what I can join on in this case*;
```

I am open to an easier approach, this logic is just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can `cross join` the list of distinct coaches with all dates to generat combinations, then bring the table with a `left join`:

```
select d.dt, c.coach, count(t.coach) no_coachees
from (select distinct coach from mytable) c
cross join generate_series('2019-01-01'::date, '2022-12-31'::date, '1 day':: interval) d(dt)
left join mytable t on t.coach = c.coach and t.entry_date <= d.dt and t.exit_date > d.dt
group by d.dt, c.coach
```

Then you can use another level of aggregation to get the monthly average:

```
select date_trunc('month', d.dt) d_month, coach, avg(no_coachees) avg_coaches
from (
    select d.dt, c.coach, count(t.coach) no_coachees
    from (select distinct coach from mytable) c
    cross join generate_series('2019-01-01'::date, '2022-12-31'::date, '1 day':: interval) d(dt)
    left join mytable t on t.coach = c.coach and t.entry_date <= d.dt and t.exit_date > d.dt
    group by d.dt, c.coach
) t
group by date_trunc('month', d.dt), coach
```

Comment: It seems to work, just the current month seems too low? Is there maybe any adjustment for the current month needed

Comment: @Aww: there is nothing special about the current month in the query, so the results should be consistend with other months.

Comment: There are some coachees that only have one status, it is visible in the data because they have the same entry and exit status as well as entry and exit date. Does this passage `left join mytable t on t.coach = c.coach and t.entry_date <= d.dt and t.exit_date > d.dt` excludes them from being counted?